# Перевод в мировые координаты

Tags: java, opengl, opengles, lwjgl

Есть координаты мыши: `mousePos` , есть матрица view - `view`, есть матрица перспективной проекции: `pMatrix`. Я перевожу координаты в мировые: нахожу обратную матрицу проекции и обратную матрицу view и умножаю на координаты мыши. Координаты начала `z=4`, координаты конца `z=-100`.

В первом случае у меня получились такие координаты: `mouseDir1 = (-0.1985  0.02887  4)`, а во втором такие: `mouseDir2 = (-0.1985  0.02887  -100)`.

Почему координаты `x,y` одинаковые?

```
private Vector3f getCoord(MouseInput mouseInput,float z){
        int wdwWitdh = 640;
        int wdwHeight =640;

        Vector2d mousePos = mouseInput.getCurrentPos();
        float x = (float)(2 * mousePos.x) / (float)wdwWitdh - 1.0f;
        float y = 1.0f - (float)(2 * mousePos.y) / (float)wdwHeight;

        Matrix4f invProjectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        invProjectionMatrix.set(pMatrix);
        invProjectionMatrix.invert();
        Vector4f tmpVec = new Vector4f();
        tmpVec.set(x, y, z, 0);
        tmpVec.mul(invProjectionMatrix);
        tmpVec.z = z;
        tmpVec.w = 0.0f;

        Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f().set(view);
        Matrix4f invViewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        invViewMatrix.set(viewMatrix);
        invViewMatrix.invert();
        tmpVec.mul(invViewMatrix);
        Vector3f mouseDir1 = new Vector3f();
        mouseDir1.set(tmpVec.x, tmpVec.y, tmpVec.z);

        ///ТЕСТОВАЯ ПРОВЕРКА Z=-100;
        //конеч координаты луча
        Vector4f tmpVec1 = new Vector4f();
        tmpVec1.set(x, y, -100, 1.0f);
        tmpVec1.mul(invProjectionMatrix);
        tmpVec1.z =-100f;
        tmpVec1.w = 0.0f;
        tmpVec1.mul(invViewMatrix);
        Vector3f mouseDir2 = new Vector3f();
        mouseDir2.set(tmpVec1.x, tmpVec1.y, tmpVec1.z);
        System.out.println();
        return mouseDir1;
    }
```

**В итоге получается такой луч:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как-то вопрос не очень сформулирован. x, y одинаковые потому, что так посчитала ваша формула. Возможно это правильный результат, если у вас камера ориентирована в направлении оси Z. Но судя по картинки линия должна идти в глубь сцены, а не по диагонали. Вообще не поятно зачем вы делаете вот это tmpVec1.z =-100f;   tmpVec1.w = 0.0f; после умножения на матрицу проекции.

Comment: @Unick делал по учебнику: https://github.com/lwjglgamedev/lwjglbook/blob/master/chapter26/src/main/java/org/lwjglb/game/MouseBoxSelectionDetector.java

Comment: В принципе, если ваша камера смотрит в направлении оси Z, то координаты x, y и должны быть одинаковые.

Comment: @Unick тогда луч рисуется не прямой линией , а как видите на скриншоте - он кривой

Comment: @Unick мне нужно, чтобы он выводился так же как в ортогональной проекции, т.е проецировалась в точку

Comment: @Санев, а у вас ортогональная проекция или перспективная?

Comment: @Unick перспективная. И нужно это сделать в перспективной

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь вам необходимо разделить tmpVec.x и tmpVec.y на tmpVec.w после применения оратной матрицы проекции.

Comment: @Unick в том учебнике это не делается. а так да, надо . так что не в этом дело

Comment: В учебнике не делали, видимо, потому что они расчитывали луч для выделения объектов, а не луч, который будет точкой при перспективной проекции.

Comment: @Unick а мне нужно построить область выделения и выделить все объекты, попавшие в эту область

Comment: Тогда ваш луч, не должен быть точкой, а должен быть отрезком, т.к. перспективная проекция.

Comment: @Unick а если мне нужно рассчитать луч для выделения, что нужно сделать?

Comment: Я думаю вам нужно найти 4 точки в экранных координатах и из каждой построить вектор. В результате у вас получится 4 ребра усечёной пирамиды выделения. Также можно нарисовать остальные рёбра, чтобы пирамида была похожа на пирамиду. Но я бы навашем месте переформулировал вопрос, если у вас уже другая проблема.

Comment: @Unick это я нашел. но у меня получился параллелипипед ( я использую ортогональную проекцию)